# cocos2d game, ccparticle system texture messed up

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, particles

my game use several particle systems. every time i use the first particle system, stars.plist for example, the next particle to be displayed will use the texture of stars.plist. (so if next particle is rain, then will be a rain of stars :(
I use [ARCH_OPTIMAL_PARTICLE_SYSTEM particleWithFile: @""], like:

```
CCParticleSystem* rain = [ARCH_OPTIMAL_PARTICLE_SYSTEM particleWithFile:@"rain.plist"];
[self addChild:rain z:-1];
```

and before initializing the rain, i have a call to preload the particle simply using:

```
[ARCH_OPTIMAL_PARTICLE_SYSTEM particleWithFile:@"rain.plist"];
```

then if my next particle to play is meteor.plist, the texture used is still the rain.plist's texture.

i use the same way to display meteor:

```
    NSString* fn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"meteor%i.plist", random];
    CCParticleSystem* meteor = [ARCH_OPTIMAL_PARTICLE_SYSTEM particleWithFile:fn];
```

I've tried CCParticleQuad and CCParticlePoint, in both 3gs and iPhone 4 and simulator, but still the same problem.

Comment: How do you provide the texture? Is it encoded in the `.plist` file or is it a separate file? I've had similar problems with textures that are embedded in the plist before, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: so then you changed to separated files and it worked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the texture data is embedded within the `.plist` file, cocos2d will extract that data and store it as a texture internally. The texture is stored with the texture filename as key, so if you have two particle-systems that use the same texture-filename internally, then the texture that was loaded *first* will be applied for all subsequent uses of the same texture filename!

An easy way to check this is looking at your `.plist` file and search the `textureFileName` key. This key should be different for each texture. Since the image-data is embedded in your `.plist` file, you can change this value to anything you want.. eg. `starparticle.png` for your stars, `rainparticle.png` for the rain, etc. Just use something unique for every unique texture.

If that fails, you could still apply the texture manually, by loading it from a file like this:

```
[rain setTexture: [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:"particleTexture.png"]];
```

Comment: some of my particle use (null).tiff as textureFileName. what should i do?

Comment: @Let'sSpotIt just edit the file and give each texture an unique filename... as I wrote in my answer. Eg. `rainparticle.png` for the rain particle system and `starparticle.png` in the star particle system etc...

Comment: i changed it anyway, and it worked. i wonder why particle designer set the texture to have the same name.